# AngularJs diretive with ng-repeat in template and updated data set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jcarousel

Here is a [testcase](http://plnkr.co/edit/YRtiWk3fYyoIfOBHxqZ9?p=preview) for this question. I'm trying to use [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) in my angularjs application. To do this I created directive that work just fine.

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('jcarousel',
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {feeds: '=', active_partner: '='},
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="(k, feed_item) in feeds  | filter: { partner_id: active_partner.id }">{{feed_item.text}}</li></ul>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl){
          c = 3;
          item_margin = 10;
          item_padding = 10;
          $(elem).addClass('carousel');
          cw = $('.carousel ul').width();
          iw = (cw-item_margin*c - c*item_padding*2) / c;
          scope.$watch('feeds', function(feeds){
             if (feeds.length){
              $('.carousel ul li').width(iw);
              $(elem).jcarousel({scroll: 1});
              $('.jcarousel-next').html('<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>');
              $('.jcarousel-prev').html('<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>');
            }
          });
        }
      };
    }
  );
```

The usage is very easy:

```
<label>
  Filter:
  <select ng-model="active_partner" ng-options="partner as partner.name for partner in partners"></select>
</label>
<p>Count: {{ feeds.length }}</p>
<div jcarousel feeds="feeds" active_partner="active_partner"></div>
```

I need to filter feeds in carousel and for some reasons when jcarousel applied after filtering it cause some mess in html:

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by the `ul` contains old list items. I just checked it out and it works just fine - the item count and the items displayed match...

Comment: Even the filter, that is the partner ID selected matches with the partner Ids that are shown in the list (post filter) - could you give some more information when you say "everything is messed up"?

Comment: @callmekatootie, sorry, I updated question and link to testcase. Problem is a bit different now.

Comment: You have to be more specific when you say "..causes some mess in html.."! What is the "mess"? I can see only that the count displayed is incorrect - is that the mess that you speak of?

Comment: @callmekatootie, no, try to change value for filter and you'll see it. Image attached.

Comment: It seems like from time to time jcarousel library was not loadeded in my testcase. Fixed that.